# Can't build docker image from Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, build, spotify-docker-client

Hello I'm trying to build a Docker image from a Docker file and get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not acquire image ID or digest following build
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444) ~[guava-21.0.jar:na]
>       at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$BuildProgressHandler.getImageId(DefaultDockerClient.java:298) ~[docker-client-8.11.7.jar:8.11.7]
>       at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$BuildProgressHandler.access$1200(DefaultDockerClient.java:287) ~[docker-client-8.11.7.jar:8.11.7]
>       at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1481) ~[docker-client-8.11.7.jar:8.11.7]

I can build the same exact Dockerfile from the command line, but I can't debug this as the stack trace isn't very informative. Below I leave some information that may be relevant:

#### Docker version:

Client:
 Version:      17.03.2-ce
 API version:  1.27
Server:
 Version:      17.03.2-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)

#### spotify/docker-client version: 8.11.7

#### How I call the docker build function:

```
final AtomicReference<String> imageIdFromMessage = new AtomicReference<>();

final String returnedImageId = dockerClient.build(

Paths.get("/absolute/path/to/folder"), image.getImageName(), dockerfilefilename,new ProgressHandler() {
    @Override
    public void progress(ProgressMessage message) throws DockerException {

        final String imageId = message.buildImageId();

        if (imageId != null) {
            imageIdFromMessage.set(imageId);
        }
    }
});
```

I can submit any other relevant info and would appreciate any help or ideas.

Edit to add requested info:

`image` is a personal data representation of a docker image, the only relevant thing about it is it has the name I want to tag the docker.

`dockerfilefilename` again is just a string that contains the filename of the dockerfile. For example, the string "Dockerfile".

`dockerClient` is an instance of DockerClient. It was created like this:

`

```
    DockerClient dc = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build();
    final RegistryAuth registryAuth = RegistryAuth.builder() //TODO change to external config
            .email("REDACTED")
            .username("REDACTED")
            .password("REDACTED")
            .build();
    final int statusCode = dc.auth(registryAuth);

    return dc;
```

`

I have checked and the status code is in fact 200. I've tried many Docker commands with the driver which are successful.

Comment: where are `dockerClient`, `image`, and `dockerfilefilename` declared, and what are they

Comment: I edited the page to include the requested information.

Comment: Any chance that you fixed or worked around the problem? I've encountered the same issue yesterday and up till now have no clue why is it happening :(

Comment: I got the same message from maven plugin and I was able to solve it by removing `.dockerignore` file: https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/25#issuecomment-310667051

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem (as I've stated in comment to the question) and managed to fix it. The error that you get is a generic one and results from a failed sanity check inside the Docker client code that can be caused by a myriad of different things.

To get the specific reason that caused the sanity check fail you can look into `message.error()` in the progress handler - in my case the error message that was there was very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the following problem at my end. In my dockerfile, the maintainer was mis-spelled.
Please debug by trying to build the image using docker build -t  .

Answer (score 0):

In the Dockerfile, had added an environment variable but missed ENV.

Correct:
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=keycloak

Bad:
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=keycloak